# Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server

Update table set Test = Convert(varchar(53), Cast(Phone_Number as Decimal))

Comment: What data types are Test and Phone_Number?

Answer (score 3):

if Phone_Number has any alphabetic or symbol characters it will fail when CASTing it to DECIMAL:

```
Update table set Test = Convert(varchar(53), Cast(Phone_Number as Decimal))
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your question is very vague, but you could try:

```
Update YourTable
    SET Test=CASE 
                 WHEN ISNUMERIC(Phone_Number)=1 THEN Convert(varchar(53), Cast(Phone_Number as Decimal)) --this is your code unchanged
                 ELSE Phone_Number
             END
...
```

Comment: If the UPDATE is for every row in the table (example code does not have a WHERE), then if only one `Phone_Number` has a bad character the entire UPDATE will fail.  Run `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(Phone_Number)=0` to find all the "bad" rows.